# Creating XML using python Element tree libarary

Tags: xml, oracle, python-3.4, elementtree

Can you please help me with the below requirement.I have tried explaining as much as possible about this requirement. Please do let me know if you need any further information. Thanks in advance for your reply.

I have a oracle table with the following data:

```
Tag_name, tag_value
empname Smith
empno   5102
sal     600
deptno   10
empname  Jhon
empno    4102
sal     800
deptno   20
```

and my xml should look like

```
<employeedetails>
   <employee>
      <empname>Smith</empname>
      <empno>5102</empno>
      <sal>600</sal>
      <deptno>10</deptno>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <empname>john</empname>
      <empno>4102</empno>
      <sal>800</sal>
      <deptno>20</deptno>
   </employee>
<employeedetails>
```

below is the code am using to generate the XML

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom
import cx_Oracle

def prettify(elem):
"""Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
"""
rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent=" ")

db = cx_Oracle.connect("username/pwd@servername") 
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.arraysize = 500
cursor.execute("select * from employee") parameter
top = Element('employeedetails')
child = SubElement(top,'employee')
for i in cursor:
sub_child = SubElement(child, i[1])
sub_child.text = i[2]
print (prettify(top))
```

instead of getting the desired output am getting ouput like below

```
<employeedetails>
   <employee>
      <empname>Smith</empname>
      <empno>5102</empno>
      <sal>600</sal>
      <deptno>10</deptno>
      <empname>john</empname>
      <empno>4102</empno>
      <sal>800</sal>
      <deptno>20</deptno>
   </employee>
<employeedetails>
```

basically for the second employee the closing tag is not getting print. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the `child = SubElement(top,'employee')` in the `for` loop, and only put the `child` in when the `empname` changes:

```
oldempname = None
for i in cursor:
    if (i[1] == 'empname') and (not i[2] == oldempname):
        child = SubElement(top,'employee')
        oldempname = i[2]
    sub_child = SubElement(child, i[1])
    sub_child.text = i[2]
```

The above code works, if the name changes, however if two records exists with the same name and those records are sequentially in `cursor`, then this will fail, **you can adapt this** to make the check unique, possibly introducing the `empno`, but I will **leave this up to you.**

Your code sample is lacking proper indents, you should think of this when posting, and avoid getting down voted for such.